# How to remove or reinstall libpng in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, libpng

I installed this libpng package for installing wps office.
libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64

From then I am having problem upgrading. command '**sudo apt-get upgrade**' gives me this problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng12-0 : Breaks: libpng12-0:i386 (!= 1.2.50-2+deb8u3) but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libpng12-0:i386 : Breaks: libpng12-0 (!= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1) but 1.2.50-2+deb8u3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I try '**sudo apt-get -f install**' I get this response.

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. The
>   following packages have unmet dependencies:  libpng12-0 : Breaks:
>   libpng12-0:i386 (!= 1.2.50-2+deb8u3) but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 is installed 
>   libpng12-0:i386 : Breaks: libpng12-0 (!= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1) but
>   1.2.50-2+deb8u3 is installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Trying '**sudo apt-get remove libpng-12.0**' gives this response.

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   compiz-plugins-default : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is
>   not going to be installed gimp : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but
>   it is not going to be installed gstreamer1.0-plugins-good : Depends:
>   libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed icoutils
>   : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be
>   installed libcairo2 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not
>   going to be installed libcupsfilters1 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>=
>   1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libfreetype6 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libgd3 :
>   Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
>   libgdal1i : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to
>   be installed libgdiplus : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is
>   not going to be installed libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>=
>   1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libgegl-0.3-0 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libgs9 :
>   Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
>   libgxps2 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be
>   installed libmagickcore-6.q16-2 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4)
>   but it is not going to be installed libopencv-highgui2.4v5 : Depends:
>   libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
>   libplymouth4 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going
>   to be installed libpoppler58 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but
>   it is not going to be installed libqt5gui5 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>=
>   1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libqt5webkit5 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libqtgui4
>   : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be
>   installed libreoffice-core : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it
>   is not going to be installed libsdl-image1.2 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>=
>   1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libsox2 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
>   libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not
>   going to be installed libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 : Depends: libpng12-0
>   (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed libwmf0.2-7 :
>   Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
>   libwxgtk3.0-0v5 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not
>   going to be installed libzvbi0 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but
>   it is not going to be installed netpbm : Depends: libpng12-0 (>=
>   1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed openjdk-7-jre : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
>   python-pygame : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going
>   to be installed tumbler : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is
>   not going to be installed vlc-nox : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4)
>   but it is not going to be installed wps-office : Depends: libpng12-0
>   but it is not going to be installed x11-apps : Depends: libpng12-0 (>=
>   1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

How can I remove this libpng version or overwrite with the correct version?

Comment: How do you installed this libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64 package? Probably using "dpkg -i" command. 
Now you can try to remove it in the same way without dependencies: sudo dpkg -r --force-depends "package" and then install libpng12 from repository via "apt-get install libpng12".

Answer (score -1):

As per @mariaczi, this worked for me:

`sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libpng12-0`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo apt-get install libpng12-0`